# Firebase web storing chats as a array in real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a chat app with firebase real time database. I store chats between 2 users as an JSON array in firebase.

Initially I when user used to send message, I used to set whole chat array. But I soon realised that's not a good idea as array will grow.

`await firebase.database().ref("chats/" + chatId).set(messages)`

When I checked official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) on how to handle Arrays in firebase, I realised I can use `push()` instead. I am doing something like this now:

```
let messageRef = firebase.database().ref("chats/" + chatId)
await messageRef.push().set(message);
```

It causes 2 problems, one is it generates `unique keys` and other is when I fetch the chat it returns `JSON object` instead of `Array`.

> I want something like this:

[image]

---

> Instead after using push I am getting:

[image]

---

What's the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see calling push() will generate a key for you.

Two solutions:

• You let Firebase generate unique key for you and transform the JSON object into an array on client side:

```
firebase.database().ref("chats/" + chatId).once("value").then(data => {
    console.log(Object.values(data.val()));
});
```

Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values

• You use your own keys ("0", "1", "2"...)

```
firebase.database().ref("chats/" + chatId).child(key).set(msg);
```

The inconvenience here is you need to know the key. You can use messages.length or store a new field with the size of messages (use **transaction** to increment it). Don't forget to write rules to prevent users overwriting.

*If you can you should use the first solution.*